# How to apply this code from 2 function to 1 function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to apply this code from 2 function to 1 function ?

First, for show element i use `show_box(value)` function.

And then for hide element i use `hide_box(value)` function.

Now i want to apply for work in 1 function , How can i do that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/k0rphh1e/

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function show_box(value)
{
    var array_val = value.split("-");
    $("#box-"+array_val[1]).stop().animate({left: '47px' , opacity: 1}, 100); 
}
</script>

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function hide_box(value)
{
    var array_val = value.split("-");
    $("#box-"+array_val[1]).stop().animate({left: '27px' , opacity: 0}, 100); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can simply pass another flag value to show or hide, then you can perform the desired operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
function show_box(value,type)
{
    var array_val = value.split("-");
    if(type=='show')
    {
        $("#box-"+array_val[1]).stop().animate({left: '47px' , opacity: 1}, 100);}
    else
    {
    $("#box-"+array_val[1]).stop().animate({left: '27px' , opacity: 0}, 100); 
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k0rphh1e/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass argument in one function

```
ex: show_box("111-1",27px,1); // you can pass argument 
function show_box(value,leftvalue,opa)
{
    var array_val = value.split("-");
    $("#box-"+array_val[1]).stop().animate({left: leftvalue , opacity: opa}, 100); 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k0rphh1e/2/)**

Comment: @downvoter : You have to put a  comment for your cost

Answer (score 2):

Use `data-*` attribute to target your `#` and hide your BOX using `display:none;`

```js
$("[data-tog]").hover(function(){
    $("#box-"+ $(this).data("tog").split("-")[1]).stop().fadeToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="like" data-tog="111-1" style="cursor: pointer;">TEST 1</div>
<div id="box-1" style="display:none;">BOX 1</div>

<div class="like" data-tog="111-8" style="cursor: pointer;">TEST 8</div>
<div id="box-8" style="display:none;">BOX 8</div>
```